# Issues with Windows IP Address vs NetBIOS name

Tags: windows-7, networking

I have Windows 7 Ultimate on my machine. I am connected through a wired network adapter to our server at work. My IP address is 192.168.2.10 and the server is 192.168.2.1.

We have some shared folders on the server. Yesterday I made some changes to VMPlayer network settings through vmnetcfg.exe. Since then, when I type \\192.168.2.1 in the explorer address bar, instead of showing the shared folders on the server, it shows my own shared folders.

It is not only explorer, other programs are behaving almost the same, and seem to be redirected to my own machine.

And if I type in the server name (\\work-server), I can reach the shared folders easily.

Does anyone have any idea what is going wrong here?

Comment: What IP address do you get if you ping the server name 'work-server'?

Comment: `C:\> ping work-server

Pinging work-server [192.168.2.1] with 32 bytes of data:  
Reply from 192.168.2.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either:

1) Two machines have the same IP address, or

2) Two networks have the same IP address range.

Comment: You were right. I had mistakenly changed the VMPlayer's NAT settings and it was in the same IP range of my network adapter. Thank you man.